# Similar iptables rules together

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

I have these rules in iptables:

```
/sbin/iptables -N LOGGING
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
/sbin/iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables Packet Dropped: " --log-level 7
/sbin/iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP
```

Can I add these rules as well or should change? Not sure, if I double logs by using "A INPUT -j LOGGING" and "A INPUT -j LOG".

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't.

`-N LOGGING` creates a custom table named `LOGGING`. It's just your custom table, where you can put your rules to group them. While it's called `LOGGING`, it doesn't do any logging by itself. You name it any way, except for the existing tables & targets.

When you target it with `-A INPUT -j LOGGING` it just tells netfilter to "step into" this table. Now it "walks" it from the first rule till the end or a terminating target - like `ACCEPT` or `DROP`, while `LOG` are non-terminating target. I.e., it will proceed with next rules after proceeding non-terminating target. So the `-j LOG` are the actual LOG target, which does the logging.

But the actual problem you might here if the example you've provided are complete is `-A LOGGING -j DROP` part. It doesn't includes any matches, and the target are set to `DROP`. Not having any match includes **every packet it passes**. So it will just drop every packet after logging. If that was your intention, then that is okay. But usually these are done with some sort of matches (like source/destination IPs, TCP/UDP ports, etc).

Comment: It seems that was an intention, because the logging prefix explicitely says the logged packed was dropped. It is logical to drop it right away.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov yes, but according to `/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING` if that's a complete command it will log & drop all input packets that way, unless there are other rules to `ACCEPT` before that.

Comment: I suspect the LOGGING is a "log and kill" target and it is to be used from any filter table chain after all necessary is enabled. I used to see firewalls set up like this. In other words, yes, if this is a complete firewall, it'll log and drop everything, but this is still a good "bare minimum" for a firewall setup.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov it's not really good, because it doesn't includes state related ACCEPT: `-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` - only with this is becomes practical to use. Because without that state based rule it will drop even every response to outgoing packets, i.e. outgoing connection won't work either due to that.

Comment: Let's agree that this is not a practical complete firewall setup, and anybody who tries to implement it like this will find out soon than "nothing works". I can imagine, say, a statum 1 time server who only accepts UDP/123 and nothing else, so it doesn't need this state match.

Comment: @NStorm Thanks. It is just a part of my Iptables rules I mentioned earlier. I gonna to add -j LOG for PSAD. So you say, LOGGING and LOG are different. In that case, I insert -j LOG.

Comment: @user14801358 LOGGING - are you custom table, you've created as I've explained. LOG - are iptables "bundled" (it' a module actually, but it's usually built by default in every modern Linux distro) target. Target - is some sort of action. Table is a set of rules.